# Does using Quartz layers slow down UITableView scrolling performance?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UIImageView that is being rounded on my custom drawn UITableViewCell:

```
        rect = CGRectMake(13, 10, 48, 48);
        avatar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        [self.contentView addSubview: avatar];

        CALayer * l = [avatar layer];
        [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [l setCornerRadius:9.0];
```

I noticed my UITableView scrolling performance decreased a little bit. Not sure if it is related to the rounded corners though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rounded corners slow down drawing a lot. Mask layers are somewhat faster. "Baking" the corners into the content (as an image or using a clipping path in your `drawRect:`) is faster still.

Allocating new views/layers will also slow down your scrolling--reuse them wherever you can (creating a `UITableViewCell` subclass that creates the subviews in `init` and destroys them in `dealloc` generally works well)

That being said, adding additional views shouldn't reduce performance noticeably.

Comment: Should I make my CALayer a member variable and then release it in dealloc? Right now it isn't being released.

Comment: If you use `[CALayer layer]`, you don't need to release it; it's already autoreleased.